# Making a valid XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert my data stored in a MySQL database to an xml file through PHP. After letting it through the feedvalidator(.org) it came out valid with 1 "recommendation":

> media:description contains bad characters

It points me towards characters like \x93 \x94 \x85 \x92. I tried solving it for ages but didn't succeed in converting these characters to what they should be.

I'm not sure if the header of my file is relevant. Just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace `\xCODE` with `&#CODE;`

```
\x93 - &#93;
```

Comment: I just noticed the \x characters are not viewable in the source code itself. So a str_replace with this method doesn't change anything. But for some reason it does show up through the validator.